# Incorporating GDAL into MSVS 2008 C++ project

Tags: c++, api, include, gdal

I've been experimenting with GDAL in python and have had some great success in it's use for terrain analysis.  My company wants to see if/how GDAL can be used in Visual Studio, as it is their primary platform.

I've downloaded and installed GDAL v1.8 in accordance with the instructions found [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnWindows) under "Building from Source"  I'm new to MSVS and not sure how to include the necessary headers to utilize the GDAL libraries in a new project.

How do I include the libraries?  Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to specify the GDAL include path in new Visual Studio projects, then you can do so under "[C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)".

Should there be any libraries to link to, then you can specify these under "[Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)".

Both of these settings can be found in your project's properties page.

Comment: Would the command go under the Property Page/Configuration Properties/C/C++/Command Line/Additional Options section?

Comment: What command? You mean the commands under "Building from Source"? I assumed you had already built GDAL and now want to use it?

Comment: Just to be sure that we're not talking about different things: Did you finalize building GDAL or are you still doing so? My answer refers to using GDAL once done building. You don't need manually to specify any command line commands inside the IDE.

Comment: I have built GDAL using this using the MSVS command line:
C:\GDAL> nmake /f makefile.vc devinstall
and the build was successful.

I have a new project and wish to incorporate the build.  I put the command:
/I C:\<file path to GDAL Build\> <my main file.cpp>

I've tried compiling, it seems to be going to the directory to include now.  Just has some errors with linking that I'll have to look into.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, but you don't have to add this command line. If you look at the sections above it in the links I have given you, you can read where to specify the libraries and include directories. Then visual studio will create all necessary command line setup for you. Ignore the "Example" parts.

Answer (score 0):

After you successfully build GDAL you need three project settings (under `Properties`):

1. Set the path to the GDAL include directory at `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `General` -> `Additional Include Directories`
2. Set the path to your lib directory (where `gdal_i.lib` is located) at `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` > `Linker` > `General` > `Additional Library Directories`
3. Add `gdal_i.lib` to `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` > `Linker` > `Input` > `Additional Dependencies`

You can then use GDAL in your C++ code as described in the [GDAL API tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html).